# Which of the following is the correct usage of: meteor/meteorite

Tags: word-usage

> I hope a meteor falls on your head.

or

> I hope a meteorite falls on your head.

And why?

[Definition of meteor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meteor):

> 1 : an atmospheric phenomenon (such as lightning or a snowfall)
>
> 2a : any of the small particles of matter in the solar system that are directly observable only by their incandescence from frictional heating on entry into the atmosphere
>
> 2b : the streak of light produced by the passage of a meteor

[Definition of meteorite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meteorite):

> a meteor that reaches the surface of the earth without being completely vaporized

Technically the rock hasn't reached the surface of the earth at the time of head hitting, but it would reach the surface of the earth without being vaporized (and probably still will) if it hadn't encountered the head. So, which is the correct term?

Comment: Please explain why your dictionary definitions don't answer your question.

Comment: Because a colleague and I do not agree, one of us think it should be meteor, and the other says meteorite.

Comment: Could you edit the question to add a brief description of the arguments that you have each given for your positions?

Comment: @BugsBuggy - Are you happy with Pam's edit? Does it explain what you were struggling with? Or was it something different?

Comment: If you are happy with @Pam's edit, then you're talking about a technicality. And that would be within the realm of subject experts, not language experts. So astronomy.se might fit better. But I see you've [cross-posted](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27683/which-of-the-following-is-the-correct-usage-meteor-meteorite) there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

"Technically the rock hasn't reached the surface of the earth at the time of head hitting" makes it a ***meteor***:

> A **[meteor](https://www.britannica.com/story/whats-the-difference-between-a-meteoroid-a-meteor-and-a-meteorite)** is a block of matter, relatively small by cosmological standards, that has descended into Earth’s atmosphere from outer space, burning a trail of dust and fire as its high speed produces friction with the air.

Note the ***after*** in the definition below:

> A **[meteorite](https://www.britannica.com/story/whats-the-difference-between-a-meteoroid-a-meteor-and-a-meteorite)** is the name for the rock that remains after a meteor strikes Earth’s surface.

<sup>src: ©2018 Encyclopædia Britannica, Inc.</sup>

Of course, technically, a "meteorite" too can very well fall on one's head, though not from the heavens.